# What tools or resources support collaborative transcription of Russian manuscripts?

Tags: transcription

In the University of Alaska's [Rasmuson library](http://library.uaf.edu/) there is a significant unpublished [manuscript about Kamchatka](https://archive.org/details/khlebnikov--kamchatka) by [Кири́лл Тимофе́евич Хле́бников](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB_%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). I find Russian cursive challenging to read, so I copied the manuscript and [uploaded it to WikiSource](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81:Khlebnikov--kamchatka.djvu) so that the text could be transcribed. Then I learned the Russian WikiSource has stricter rules about unpublished documents than the English WikiSource; novel research by notable authors is disallowed. The content was quickly [marked for deletion](https://ru.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%9A_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E&stable=0#.D0.98.D0.BD.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.81:Khlebnikov--kamchatka.djvu).

What other tools or resources exist online for collaboratively transcribing Russian manuscripts? I specify collaborative and online, because hiring a literate individual to copy out the text might be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: If this manuscript is so important that this labor should be paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at https://transkribus.eu/Transkribus/? Looks like it is what you need.

Comment: Good link, I appreciate it!